# Stuck with 'Server not reachable: unauthorized' error in Parse-Dashboard with HTTPS

Tags: parse-server

I have successfully installed parse-server on my server running Ubuntu, following the steps described in the installation guide.

My server is fine, available in `https://www.example.com/parse` with this config:

**parse-server config**

```json
{
  "appId": "app",
  "clientKey": "client",
  "masterKey": "master",
  "appName": "MyParseApp",
  "cloud": "./cloud/main",
  "serverURL": "https://www.example.com/parse",
  "masterKeyIps": [my_ips],
  "databaseURI": "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
}
```

**Apache VirtualHost config for example.com**

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com/http_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com/http_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com/https_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com/https_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/certificate/example.com.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certificate/example.com.key
    
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /parse http://localhost:1337/parse
    ProxyPassReverse /parse http://localhost:1337/parse
    ProxyPass /dashboard http://localhost:4040/dashboard
    ProxyPassReverse /dashboard http://localhost:4040/dashboard

    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

I then launch the dashboard with this command:

`nohup parse-dashboard --dev --config parse-dashboard-config.json &`

**The associated config**

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "appId": "app",
      "masterKey": "master",
      "appName": "MyParseApp",
      "iconName": "",
      "primaryBackgroundColor": "",
      "secondaryBackgroundColor": "",
      "serverURL": "https://www.example.com/parse"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
        "user": "username",
        "pass": "password"
    }
  ],
  "iconsFolder": "icons"
}
```

I have blatantly set simple `appID`/`masterKey`/`clientKey` values on purpose to make sure there is no mistake here, like a typo.

I can also access the dashboard as expected, but when I set the serverURL in the dashboard config as `https://www.example.com/parse`, I get this error:

[image]

However, if I set instead `http://www.example.com:1337/parse` for this serverURL value, I can access the dashboard and consult/update data as expected.

I have already tried several things recommended in different topics I have came across here and on [Parse-Server github repo](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server), like adding a `allowInsecureHTTP` flag as true, without success.

Could you give me some help about this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

New `parse-server` version requires `masterKeyIps` https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/8421

Adding `masterKeyIps: ['0.0.0.0/0']` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using docker.  I added the below server environment variable in my docker-compose.yml

- PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY_IPS=0.0.0.0/0